# Python AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'maketrans'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

I am receiving the below error when trying to run a command in Python 3.5.2 shell:

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:01:18) [MSC v.1900 32 bit      
(Intel)] on win32 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> folder = 'C:/users/kdotz/desktop'
>>> f = open(folder + '/genesis.txt', 'r')
>>> import operator, time, string
>>> start=time.time()
>>> genesis = {}
>>> for line in f:
line=line.split()
for word in line:
    word = word.lower()
    new_word=word.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctutation)
    if new_word in genesis:
        genesis[new_word]+=1
    else:
        genesis[new_word]=1
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 5, in <module>
new_word=word.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctutation)
AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'maketrans'
```

What am I doing incorrectly? I import string at the top of the code. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: In Python 3 `maketrans` is a method of `str`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`maketrans` is deprecated in favor of new static methods

> The `string.maketrans()` function is deprecated and is replaced by new static methods, [`bytes.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.maketrans) and [`bytearray.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.maketrans). This change solves the confusion around which types were supported by the `string` module. Now, `str`, `bytes`, and `bytearray` each have their own `maketrans` and `translate` methods with intermediate translation tables of the appropriate type.

You can use `dir()` to verify that whenever you have this kind of issue:

```
>>> import string
>>>
>>> dir(string)
['Formatter', 'Template', '_ChainMap', '_TemplateMetaclass', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_re', '_string', 'ascii_letters', 'ascii_lowercase', 'ascii_uppercase', 'capwords', 'digits', 'hexdigits', 'octdigits', 'printable', 'punctuation', 'whitespace']
>>>
```

As you can see, there is no `maketrans` in the resulted list above.

Comment: The error I get now is:                                                                                                        

`>>> for line in f:
 line=line.split()
 for word in line:
  word=word.lower()
  new_word = word.translate(str.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
  if new_word in genesis:
   genesis[new_word]+=1
  else:
   genesis[new_word]=1`

   `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#67>", line 5, in <module>
    new_word = word.translate(str.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

Comment: You need to remove `string.punctuation`

Comment: Check `str.translate()` documentation here https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 8):

Py 3.9:

```
"abcdef".translate(str.maketrans('def', 'ghi'))
```